# windowInsetsController vs windowInsetsControllerCompat? I can only access the former

Tags: android, view, android-view, custom-view, windowinsets

So i was watching this tutorial by google today here https://youtu.be/jal0l48OTxk and i figured that doing

```
        myCanvasView.systemUiVisibility = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

is now deprecated and i need to use `windowInsetsController` instead. First off, I am new to android and i don't know how to use this new thing which clearly doesn't work in the exact same way as the old API so it's not a direct replacement but rather more nuanced one. Seondly, I noticed that `windowInsetsController` is not backwards compatible and there is something like `windowInsetsControllerCompat` that exists out there. However, I am not able to access it like this:

```
        myCanvasView.windowInsetsControllerCompat
```

but

```
        myCanvasView.windowInsetsController
```

works fine. Can someone here help me out?

Answer (score 0):

WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: in  androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0  you can use this

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
WindowCompat.getInsetsController(getWindow(), myCanvasView);
```

instead of:

```
myCanvasView.windowInsetsController
```

See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowCompat#WindowCompat(), and https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive